# Multiple statements in single transaction with phantom

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

Is it possible to execute multiple queries in one transaction with phantom? I don't mean batch inserts/updates, but executing one query based on results of another.
Didn't find anything on the matter in the docs. Have a guess, though, it's meant like that, due to the specifics of Cassandra and NoSQL.

Comment: this is not possible. you need to perform two queries.

Comment: @Laxmikant thank you

Comment: @jsi Answer is correct, unfortunately this is not possible, but it's because of Cassandra. Batches are used to guarantee atomicity usually, so where possible use batches, that's really why they exist. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html

Answer (score 0):

As @Laxmikant noted, and I later discovered, this not possible for Cassandra because of the eventual consistency. This is a *consistency - availability - partition tolerance* tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as the project lead on phantom.

I think you are on the money with batches. They have some restrictions, and they are not 100% what you want, but it's certainly possible to achieve some of this.

> Combines multiple data modification language (DML) statements (such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE) to achieve atomicity and isolation when
>   targeting a single partition, or only atomicity when targeting
>   multiple partitions.
>
> A batch applies all DML statements within a single partition before
>   the data is available, ensuring atomicity and isolation. A
>   well-constructed batch targeting a single partition can reduce
>   client-server traffic and more efficiently update a table with a
>   single row mutation.

In the strictest sense, you cannot depend on the result of a previous query in an atomic way, but I would try if at all possible to replicate the functionality within a batch, as it's likely going to be your only option of achieving a similar SQL like guarantee.